# Speed up union for tessellating polygons

Tags: polygon, union, nettopologysuite

I'm doing a union of a large number of complicated polygons using nettopologysuite and it is very slow.  As these polygons are perfectly tessellating is there something I can do to speed things up?

What I've tried so far

```
List<IGeometry> collection = GetLargeCollectionOfComplicatedMultiPolygons();

x = new NetTopologySuite.Operation.Union.UnaryUnionOp(collection).Union();//00:24:05

x = new NetTopologySuite.Operation.Union.CascadedPolygonUnion(collection).Union();//00:36:17

x = new GeometryCollection(collection.ToArray()).Buffer(0);//00:07:17
```

I've also tried to do stuff in parallel but it's not really helped.

Comment: How are you doing the union? Please, provide some code so we can see how to improve it.

Comment: @cag code sample attached, the buffer(0) trick is the best I've found which I hadn't tried when I'd posted the question but I still feel this should be quicker given that the polygons perfectly tessellate.

Comment: You tried all the ways of union I know in NTS. There is one last thing you could try, but I've never tested it in NTS, so I don't know how it will perform. It requieres several steps. 1- Extract the segments of the polygons. 2- Remove the duplicate segments, so you keep only the boundary segments. 3- Polygonize the result.